# Flutter web Vrouter routing navigate back but path getting erased automatically?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-navigation, flutter-desktop

I'm using VRouter for flutter web routing.
When I click on a button to go to next route it shows the new route for a brief moment and then it's vanished. You can see in gif below it comes for a second and then goes away..

Problem is that due to this I'm not able to nevigate back to previous page

[image]

Here is my routings

```
class AppRouters extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return VRouter(
      title: "Portal",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
      mode: VRouterMode.history,
      logs: VLogs.info,
      routes: [
        VWidget(path: '/', widget: LoginPage()),
        VWidget(path: '/home', widget: HomePage()),
        tagVGuard(),
        HrVGuard(),
      ],
    );
  }

  VGuard tagVGuard() => VGuard(
        beforeEnter: (vRedirector) async {
          String? check = await UserController.getUserType();
          return check == 'tag' ? null : vRedirector.to('/');
        },
        stackedRoutes: [
          VWidget(path: '/tag', widget: TagDashboardPage()),
          VWidget(path: '/tag/candidates', widget: CandidateListPage()),
          VWidget(path: '/tag/employee', widget: EmployeeListPage()),
        ],
      );
```

And here is my page which is causing problem

```
class EmployeeListPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "EmployeeListPage",
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: MyAppBar("EmployeeListPage"),
        body: Body(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: ApiService.getAllEmployees(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("ERROR: ${snapshot.error}");
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return GridBody(snapshot.data);
        }
        return Text("Loading DATA");
      },
    );
  }
}

class GridBody extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<EmployeeModel> employeeList;

  GridBody(this.employeeList);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Wrap(
          spacing: 10,
          runSpacing: 10,
          children: List.generate(
            employeeList.length,
            (index) => GridCard(employeeList[index]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GridCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final EmployeeModel employee;

  GridCard(this.employee);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.black26,
      width: 400.0,
      height: 100.0,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(employee.id.toString()),
          Text(employee.name),
          Text(employee.role),
          Text(employee.email),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, VRouter dev here. Could you specify: `Problem is that due to this I'm not able to navigate back to previous page`? Do you mean using the browser back button, or the app bar, or something else?

Comment: Actually both, browser back button is not working and if we just create a simple button to navigate back it also doesn't work.

Comment: Oh I might know. You have a nested `MaterialApp`. Change it to `VMaterialApp` and let me know if it works :)